# use regex in java with non printable chars

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm using regex found here ([link](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/domain-name-regular-expression-example/)) to extract domain string that works fine.

the regex is

```html
^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$
```

I'm wondering, how could I change it in order to match domain which contains a non printable character instead of dot (.) ?

I know that regex code are like \x01, \x02, etc..
but if I replace dot with one of them, the regex doesn't match anymore

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. will match any single character regardless of whether it is printable. Your current group [A-Za-z0-9-] restricts it. You could change this to "any character except literal dot"... i.e. [^.].

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^((?!-)[^.]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$");
System.out.println(regex.matcher("\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004..com").find()); // => false
System.out.println(regex.matcher("\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004.com").find()); // => true
System.out.println(regex.matcher("google.com").find()); // => true
```

If you're attempting to validate user entry of IDNs (international domain names), note note that there are [new gTLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) that contain non alphanumeric characters
Example .شبكة (.network).

Comment: Interesting... so if I have this kind of TLD in my byte array, I should decode it as UTF32 , is there a way to detect with regex as well? the best would be have a regex for all kind of domain...

Answer (score 0):

Your dot is escaped here.

You need to remove the double-escape (`\\`) and replace the dot with a literal to match it.

You could also just remove the double escape and keep the dot, which would match any character.